# Magento select customer default shipping address in header

Tags: magento

Is possible to put default shipping address dropdown selection to header?
I need to have possibility for set default shipping address on every page.
My Magento ver 1.9

Comment: Do you want to get current logged in customer's default shipping address am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the implementataion.

in header.phtml. copy below code

```
<div class="customer-shipping-address">
  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header_shipping'); ?>
</div>
```

in page.xml copy below code under "header" block

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="page.header.shipping" as="header_shipping" template="page/html/shipping.phtml"/>
```

create shipping.phtml under the "page/html" and write below code.

```
<ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
       <li class="wide">
           <div class="input-box">
              <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('shipping') ?>
           </div>
       </li>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>
```